# Unity Shader - Access Property

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Background**:
I created a dissolve Shader using the lightweight render pipiline, in Shader Graph by drag & drop. My object "dissolves" over time & fades in again. (Youtube "Brackeys Dissolve Shader")

**Goal**: 
I want to change the _edgecolor as soon the object has been dissolved.

I can change the color via:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_edgecolor", Color.blue);
```

**Problem**:
How do i access the "Alpha" which seems to be modified by the shader, and would be a good indicator if the object is dissolved, right ?!

I tried to get the Alpha

```
Color c = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.GetColor("_Color");
```

`c.a = ....`

won't work, because -> Material doesn't have a color property '_Color'

[Here's a Screenshot of my ShaderGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du5Ja.png)

Comment: use the ```Reference``` field of your shader graph's variables in Shader graph window.

Comment: But **how to access The 'Alpha' of the "PBR Master"** ?

or.. The Cube is "dissolving" - so how do i know when it's "invisible" - ?

Comment: You can create a Vector1 variable make it public and multiply that with your existing input to Alpha now you can control the alpha. and the **PBR Master** I'm afraid you can't directly assess that node. You can make corresponding public variables to access/change the values of **PBR Master Node**

Comment: It is either the **Emission / Alpha Values** that are **determining the visibilty, right?** And **i need to check their Current Value at runtime in order to determine if my material is visible or not**

i tried your suggestion but it only adds the possibilty to add a property that i had to set to 1 in order to keep the same behaviour & won't changed at runtime. https://imgur.com/a/P59jMjO

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't check the emission value. even if you could I won't suggest doing that cause it's a texture which is generated by unity and checking that every frame would require lots of computing. instead, you can use a property to control the emission and use that to check if the object is visible or not.

Comment: thx 4 your effort.

The thing is: In my ShaderGraph there's the Time Node which is computing certain Values over Time and the result is written to the Emission & Alpha values ...the Object gets visible & invisible.

Since they're writiable within ShaderGraph i do assume that one must be able to access them without, i mean there's code behind all this drag & drop gui that is manipulating these values.

Comment: Would [ticking Expose on your property and giving it a reference name to use in script](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/07/10/2018-2-is-now-available/#property) be of help?